How can I get the raw body content of a post or put request in the .net minimal API?
How can I get the raw body content of a post or put request in the .net minimal API?
I tried it like this:
app.MapPut($"/{controllerName}", async ([FromBody] BasisTypeDto dto, IRepository repo, HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) => {

    BuilderMinimalApiActionResult<object>.MakeActionResult(Crud.Update(dto, repo, host, DefaultElasticIndex)); }
)
    .AddEndpointFilter(async (efiContext, next) => {

        var s = efiContext.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();

        s.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        var reader = new StreamReader(efiContext.HttpContext.Request.Body);

        var rawMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return await next(efiContext);
    })

But in rawMessage I get an empty string, although the length of efiContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength == 112

The body is a stream and can only be read once; I suspect you'll find that .net has read it already when it made your [FromBody] BasisTypeDto, so you can't read it again with the stream reader. Do you really need to have the object deser'd and also have the raw? Perhaps then don't have the arg, read the raw and invoke deser yourself

@flackoverstow. Yes, exactly. Thanks

The request body could be read only once. If you want to read multiple times, you should enable the buffering.
More details, you could refer to below codes:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering(); // Allows request body to be read multiple times
    await next();
});
app.MapPut("/test", async ([FromBody] BasisTypeDto dto) =>
{
 
    return new OkResult();
}).AddEndpointFilter(async (efiContext, next) => {

    //var s = efiContext.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
    efiContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    //s.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    var reader = new StreamReader(efiContext.HttpContext.Request.Body);

    var rawMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return await next(efiContext);
});

Result:

